# webpart value gone after page reload

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2013

first of all i am using sharepoint, 
basically my objective is easy, what i want to do is to update my webpart properties and use it for future.

```
string _SavedCondition;
[WebBrowsable(false),
Category("New"),
Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
WebDisplayName("ConditionStore")]
public string SavedCondition
{
    get;
    set;           

}
```

above is my webpart control

i have a button, when i click my button, it will update value of my control

i upaded by using below code

```
 this.WebPart.SavedCondition = "Admin";
```

okay, so here is my problem, when i clicks my button, my value is updated and able to display, however when i closed my browser and redirect to the page again, the value is gone.

as per sharepoint UI practise, once there are changes in web part properties, user is required to click on apply to save it. however how can i do that in programming way? please lets me know if i need to provide more info or any unclear message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after i done a long research, finally i did it

```
  SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                SPFile file = web.GetFile(<PageURL>);
                SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = file.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);                
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                CustomWebPart webPart = (CustomWebPart)manager.WebParts[this.ID];
  //saved condition is my properties, u can find it from my questions above
                webPart.SavedCondition = "Something"; 
                manager.SaveChanges(webPart);
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

when i performed AllowUnsafeUpdates and SaveChanges, my data is stored in webpart =)